# XS:any schemavalidation

Tags: xsd

I am getting validation error in the below xsd .

cos-nonambig: "http://alert.schemas.tr.com/TriggerSynchronizationService/Data/2010-02-08/":resyncRequestID and WC[##any] (or elements from their substitution group) violate 
 "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

I think i did not declare xs:any properly.

```
<xs:complexType name="GenerationTriggerData">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="resyncRequestID" type="xs:int" /> 
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userID" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="alertID" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="triggerID" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="logicalType" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="version" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="state"  type="q1:State_Enum" /> 
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="criteria"     xmlns:q2="http://expressions.schemas.tfn.thomson.com/2006-09-04/" type="q2:ExpressionRoot"    /> 
    <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>                              
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSD doesn't allow for ambiguous content. UPA is about the parser being able to figure out where it is relative to the XSD, unambiguously; even [look-ahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-ahead_%28backtracking%29) is not allowed.

Since your **`xsd:any`** can be (##)any namespace, then `resyncRequestID` would match it; in that case, is that the first (optional)  one, or the wildcard? Here the content is clearly ambigous and no look-ahead would help.

One way is to have xsd:any definition changed such that it won't match any of the content preceding it. Constraining the namespace is always an easy way to do it.

Alternatively, make the particle right before xsd:any mandatory. This way the reader would know where "the wild" begins...

If that is not an option, introduce a special "marker" tag right before xs:any; it must be mandatory!

The above are typically called "refactoring an XSD" to satisfy XSD's UPA design constraint.